# Is it possible to implement `apply` in a Lisp using `eval`?

Tags: lisp, racket

I am learning Racket (a Scheme-like Lisp), and i have tried to do something like `(apply + '(1 2))` but without using `apply`, and i failed.  I was almost sure before that `apply` can be somehow simulated using `eval`, but now i have doubts.

So, my question is: can `apply` be implemented in Racket (or other Lisp) using only `eval` and other basic operations?  That is, how to make this work:

```lisp
{ define [my-apply f arg]
  ;; what does go here?
}
(my-apply + (list 1 2)) ; => 3
```

Comment: Sure it is. Hint: The trick is to pass a list of functor and arg to the `eval` without evaluating the list yourself, so you need to use `(list ... )` and `(quote ...)`.

Comment: Is there a solution that works if `arg` references a lexically-scoped variable?

Comment: Something you have to consider is that eval calls apply. So if you define my-apply by calling eval which in turn calls apply, have you really defined my-apply without using apply?

Comment: @WuHoUnited, this would be fine for me, i am not considering in this question how `eval` is implemented.

Comment: .. but please do not do this in production code.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
(defun my-apply (function arglist)
  (eval (cons function (mapcar (lambda (x) (list 'quote x)) arglist))))
(my-apply '+ '(1 2 3))
6
(my-apply '+ '(1 a 3))
*** - +: A is not a number
```

1. Note that you cannot do `(my-apply #'+ '(1 2 3))`, this would require an extra step.
2. Note that you have to quote `arglist` elements to avoid double evaluation (Thanks to Ryan for catching that!)

Comment: (eval (list* 'funcall (list 'quote function) arglist))

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I wanted to avoid `funcall` too

Comment: How about `(my-apply '+ '((recursively-delete-all-files "/")))`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this one (in Racket):

```lisp
{ define [my-apply func args]
  { define ns-for-eval (make-base-namespace) }
  (eval (cons func args) ns-for-eval)
}

(my-apply + (list 1 2)) ; => 3
```

Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: I see that there is an issue with the elements of args being evaluated themselves. I can probably quote args element-wise, like in the answer of sds, but it starts looking too complicated.